# Python reading data from input file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read specific data from an input file. How can I read it?

For example my file has data like:

```
this is my first line
this is my second line.
```

So I just want to read `first` from the first line and `secon` from the second line.

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is a good starting point. Refer to the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for additional guidance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: StackOverflow is for coding issues. Not for code requests. My answer is a single exception for you as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for your needs but please read the comments above.

```
# ----------------------------------------
# open text file and write reduced lines
# ----------------------------------------
#this is my first line
#this is my second line.
pathnameIn = "D:/_working"
filenameIn = "foobar.txt"
pathIn = pathnameIn + "/" + filenameIn

pathnameOut = "D:/_working"
filenameOut = "foobar_reduced.txt"
pathOut = pathnameOut + "/" + filenameOut

fileIn = open(pathIn,'r')
fileOut = open(pathOut,'w')

print(fileIn)
print(fileOut)

i = 0

# Save all reduced lines to a file.
for lineIn in fileIn.readlines():
    i += 1 # number of lines read
    lineOut = lineIn[11:16]
    fileOut.writelines(lineOut +"\n") 

print("*********************************")
print("gelesene Zeilen: " + str(i))
print("*********************************")

fileIn.close()
fileOut.close()
```

Comment: i am running the code . but it is giving me syntax error when i am checking char with 'first'
fileIn= open("test.txt",'r')
for lineIn in fileIn.readlines():
    i += 1 # number of lines read
    k = lineIn[3:9]
    if k = 'first':
        print(k)
    else:
        print('wrong')

Comment: @ankit - please clean up your question as mentioned by comments above.